# How to "use multiple redux-middleware" with reactjs app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga

I'm using **redux-thunk** and **redux-saga** as **middleware** and my action call is successful but when I reload the page data is lost, the lifecycle method is called but it doesn't make a call to the server ??

I have tried this way but not helpful...
please help me out with this. Thanks

```
const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware, routeMiddleware, thunk];
 const store = createStore(persistedReducer, initialState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)));
```

So I tried doing it like this

```
import {applyMiddleware, compose, createStore} from "redux";
import reducers from "../reducers/index";
import {routerMiddleware} from "react-router-redux";
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import rootSaga from "../sagas/index";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';


const history = createHistory();
const routeMiddleware = routerMiddleware(history);
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware, routeMiddleware];
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStore(reducers, initialState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk,...middlewares)));

  sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);


  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('../reducers/index', () => {
      const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers/index');
      store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
    });
  }
  return store;
}
export {history};
```

**Edit:**

Add component code, as discussed in comments:

```
let data=[];

import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import actionName from './actions';

class extends MyClass Component { 
    constructor(props) { 
        super(props) 
        this.state = { newdata: [], }; 
    } 
    componentDidMount(){ 
        this.props.actionName(); 
        data == this.props.reducerName() 
        this.state.newdata.push(data); 
    } 
    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div> here I'm mapping data </div> 
        ) 
    }
} 

const mapStateToProps = (state) => { return { reducerName: state.reducerName, } } 
export default (mapStateToProps,{actionName}) (MyClass);
```

Comment: When you say reload, do you mean you are refreshing the page? If so, your data will not persist as the Redux state does not persist by default.

Comment: @tombraider  Good to hear from you, I already tried using redux-persist but it just persists the state and do not update the state.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Could you expand on your question so we can see how you're using your Redux store. Try to include a step by step journey of what you're trying to achieve as it will help us to help you :)

Comment: @tombraider  I have class component in which I'm using componentDidMount method to call action //action call
`export const actionName = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
      const response = await API_KEY.get('/users');
      dispatch({ type: ACTION_GET, payload: response.data.response })
  }
};`

Comment: @tombraider //reducer
`export default (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTION_REGISTER: {
      return action.payload
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}`

Comment: OK, doesn't look like you're binding your action correctly. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've pasted, it doesn't look like you're binding your actions to the component correctly. You need to bind your action creators to the component, like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import actionName from './actions';

class seaportViewAll extends Component {
    ...
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => { return { reducerName: state.reducerName, } } 
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => { return bindActionCreators({ yourAction: actionName }) }
export default (mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(seaportViewAll);
```

See Redux documentation for more detail: https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators

Comment: Yes, I have used bindActionCreators as I had single action and to avoid lengthy comment I binded my action that way. I'm able to fetch data but while navigating through another webpage my component becomes stateless. Data is displayed once and then gone